# Prove that an ideal generated by a system of trigonometric equations is not maximal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a situation involving two given sequences of 3 dimensional vectors with real coefficients: $A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3$ and $B_0, B_1, B_2, B_3$.
I have to find a rotation $r$ in $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ that satisfies the system of equations $$ 
det(r(A_1) \times B_1, r(A_2)\times B_2, r(A_3) \times B_3) = 0 \\
det(r(A_0) \times B_0, r(A_2)\times B_2, r(A_3) \times B_3) = 0 \\
det(r(A_0) \times B_0, r(A_1)\times B_1, r(A_3) \times B_3) = 0 \\
$$
where $\times$ is the cross product. 
At first sight we have a system with three equations (of degree at most 6) with three indeterminate (the angles that determine the rotation $r$). In this case I thought I could expect at most $6^3$ solutions, but when I tackled the problem in a numeric way using Newton's algorithm I found many more that this. Being convinced that those solutions were clusters of approximate solutions to the true solutions I decided to plot them to have a visual confirmation. Great was my astonishments that those approximations formed a nice 1-dimensional curve. In each solution the Jacobian determinant was not quite zero but had one eigenvalue that was very close to zero. Is it possible to prove that this system of equations doesn't generate a maximal ideal? Is it possible to find an algebraic dependence of these equations?

Comment: Not generating a maximal ideal is *not* the same thing as the set of solutions not being zero dimensional. Maybe the question you really want answered is: Why do the solutions to these equations form a curve in $SO(3)$? (Unlike the title you have given.) Could you share where this equations came from?

Comment: @AreaMan I have to admit that you are right and that I was a little hasty in my  conclusion. But I still don't see how to handle this set of equations. Btw these equatios derive from the consideration that the planes through the origin  formed by the vectors $r(A_i)$, $B_i$  have a line in common.